# Cell-by-cell analysis of values of buildings in a city

Tags: qgis, analysis, grids-graticules

I'm absolute new in GIS.

My task is to estimate the wind energy potential in a part of a certain european city by using a given method which is based on the calculated roughness of cells of one square kilometer. The values I need here are height, ground area and projection area (direction west) of the obstacles (buildings).
I found a complete 3D modell of the city (City GML) and I have additionaly access on a administrative database including position and dimensions of all buildings - unfortunaly there is no one with knowledge able to help me getting started with the software (QGIS).

My (simple) idea is like

1. adding the grid-layer (like
   https://www.govdata.de/daten/-/details/utm-raster-hamburg ?)
2. analysing cells:
3. are there buildings in the cell?
4. saving height and ground area, calculating projection area by using length/width and position
5. calculating rougness of the cell...

(problem not thought about yet: buildings can be located in more than one cell!)

...and in the end presenting the result (the cells wind energy density per square meter) in a coloured map.

So far - I have few ideas how to concrete start with the given material. Are there some functions, tools or terms I should have a closer look at without the need to start learning the GIS science from zero?

Is it expedient to use the 3D model which is more detailed (including hills etc.) or is the QGIS-database promising more?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at existing software for wind modelling for inspiration. There are a few of these, which cater for the renewable energy market (wind modelling is one of many factors used to assess where to build wind turbines).

There's a list [here in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_energy_software).. some are proprietary, some are open source.

You could look at [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/)'s [Leeward/Windward Index](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_morphometry_15.html). SAGA and QGIS generally play quite nicely together, although this algorithm isn't available from the Processing toolkit (as of QGIS 2.14).

I've not used this in any depth (just dabbled with it on coarse DEMs) so I'm not sure how much help that is. It works on rasters, not vectors, so you'd need to convert your building elevations into a raster first.